# When stretch attributes to multiline in Haml, I got an unbalanced brackets error

Tags: haml

The following code gives me `unbalanced bracket error` at line 4

```
%ul
  - @sentences.each do |sentence|
    %li
      %a{id:"s-#{sentence.id}",
      href:"/sentence/#{sentence.id}",
      'data-type' => 'text',
      'data-url' => "/sentence/#{sentence.id}",
      'data-toggle' => 'manual'
      }= sentence.content
      %a{href:'#'}
        %i.icon-pencil



Haml::SyntaxError at /user/1/sentence
Unbalanced brackets.
file: sentences.haml location: nil line: 4
```

any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem myself, the closing `}` should not in a new line like any other languages

```
'data-toggle' => 'manual'}
  = sentence.content
```

will work

Comment: seems the important thing is indentation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930603/haml-syntax-split-a-line-to-a-couple-of-rows

Comment: not only the last `}` need to have preceding characters but the first `{` also require some following characters as well

Answer (score 4):

I found other solution it may work for the others. According to the [docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#multiline) it is required to use `|` on multiline content. Of course closing bracket can't be in the new line. Example:

```
  %a{id:"s-#{sentence.id}", |
  href:"/sentence/#{sentence.id}", |
  'data-type' => 'text', |
  'data-url' => "/sentence/#{sentence.id}", |
  'data-toggle' => 'manual'}= sentence.content
```

Comment: Old answer, I know, but this is inaccurate. You can leave out the pipes in this example because each line ends in a comma.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me. Try adding a comma after your last key-value pair.

For instance

`...
 'data-url' => "/sentence/#{sentence.id}",
 'data-toggle' => 'manual',
}`

Note the `,` after `'manual'`. This worked for me. Hope it helps someone.